# How to convert the column name to its column index in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Excel column names are like A, B, C ... AA, AB, AC up to infinite. How can i convert the column name to its column index in Haskell. I can convert index to column but couldnt make the reverse function. Can someone explain me how to write the reverse function of it ? Index to column:

```
f n = (concatMap sequence $ tail $ iterate (['A'..'Z'] :) []) !! n
```

Comment: Hint: see these as "numbers" where `A` maps to `1`, `B` to 2, etc. and for the next number, you multiply with the radix.

Comment: On a side note: as one is the inverse of the other it is a joy to test these functions.

Comment: Honestly I'm impressed that you came up with that particular solution for your index-to-column function. I think whatever solution I would have come up with would have been more basic.

I can think of some approaches for the reverse function, but @WillemVanOnsem's hint above should suffice IMHO.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem that's pretty much right, except you don't have a `0` digit in that system. and In fact after `Z` you have `AA` rather than `A0`, so it's a bit more nuanced than just converting from/to base 26. (it's actually base 26 except that in the most significant digit `A` is 1, and in the rest of the digits `A` is 0, and leading zeroes are omitted)

Comment: ^ actually made a mistake there, *least* significant digit has `A` as 0 and the rest have `A` as 1.

Comment: @M.Aroosi: well, I think it might be simpler, to first increment the value, and then perform the logic, and then decrement the value :). But indeed, there is a small semantical error in my hint :S.

Answer (score 0):

Excel columns are simply numbers in Base26, with digits A-Z.

Use `readInt` from [`Numeric`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Numeric.html).

```
xlColumnToNumberR :: ReadS Int
xlColumnToNumberR = readInt 26 -- There are 26 letters
                            isAlpha -- From 'Data.Char'
                            xlValue
  where xlValue c = ord (toUpper c) - ord 'A' + 1

xlColumnToNumber :: String -> Maybe Int
xlColumnToNumber n = case xlColumnToNumberR n of
                       [(x, "")] -> Just x
                       _ -> Nothing
```

Comment: Err... did you test this? `xlColumnToNumberR "AA" = [(0, "")]`

Comment: it gives an error. And i am trying to solve it without any library functions exept the main

Comment: actually, it's [bijective base-26](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijective_numeration) (with letters used as digits).

Comment: Sorry everyone, fixed! A = 1 in this base, not 0, as I originally had.